# How to remove google plus button message?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add goople plus 1 button in my app and when the user clicks and recommends the link, this message shows up "+1 Recommned this on Google" .How can i remove this message and display just a ballon with the number of recommendation of the link?

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
plus:size="standard"
plus:annotation="inline" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusOneButton.html#ANNOTATION_NONE Says...

> "Sets the annotation to display next to the +1 button. This can also
>   be set using the attribute plus:annotation="none|bubble|inline". "

Therefore try:

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
plus:size="standard"
plus:annotation="none" />
```